# SQL Select cases from a long table where ID is not duplicated

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery, subquery, window-functions

I have a table like below:

```
id | ncode | code
=================
1      1     ABC
1      2     DEF
2      1     ABC
3      1     ABC
4      1     ABC
4      2     DEF
```

I have two requirements:

1. All records where `ncode` == 1 and `code` == `ABC`
2. But only if `id` is not duplicated somewhere in the table (i.e., I don't want a record with `code` == `ABC` if that same `id` also has an `ncode` > 1 somewhere in the table.

`select * from table where code == "ABC" and ncode == 1` will satisfy the first requirement but I can not figure out how to satisfy the second.

My desired output given the above example table would be:

```
id | ncode | code
=================
2      1     ABC
3      1     ABC
```

Per the answer below, I have utilized a window function:

```
select *
from (
   select *,
    sum(case when ncode > 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id) cnt
   from mytable
)
where code = 'ABC' and ncode = 1 and cnt = 0 order by id
```

I then implemented the Google BiqQuery specific syntax provided by the accepted answer:

```
select id, ANY_VALUE(ncode) ncode, ANY_VALUE(code) code
from mytable
group by id
having count(1) = 1
and (cpt, ncode) = ('ABC', 1)
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: postgresql, oracle, mysql...?

Comment: I have tagged `google-bigquery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below should also work (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  ANY_VALUE(ncode) ncode, 
  ANY_VALUE(code) code
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
AND (code, ncode) = ('ABC', 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! can you explain what `count(1)` is doing exactly? I understand the `count` function and I see you're grouping by `id`, but why is the command not `having count(id) = 1` instead of `having count(1) = 1`? I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: In this case count(1) and count(id) do the same - they just simply count rows for each Id and filter out those with dups

Comment: Ok great, so I was understanding the commands correctly. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: consider voting up the answer if it helped :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (select t.*, count(*) over(partition by id, code) cnt from mytable) t
where code = 'ABC' and ncode = 1 and cnt = 1
```

This assumes no duplicate `ncode` per `code`, and no value below `1`. Else, we can be more specific in the window function:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        sum(case when ncode > 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id, code) cnt 
    from mytable 
) t
where code = 'ABC' and ncode = 1 and cnt = 0
```

Comment: I have to modify your code slightly, see edit to my original question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery that searches the table for records with the same `id` but large `ncode`.

```
SELECT t1.*
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE t1.code = 'ABC'
             AND t1.ncode = 1
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM elbat t2
                                    WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                                          AND t2.ncode > t1.ncode);
```

And by the way: Stop using double quotes for string literals. Though your DBMS might accept that, in the standard double quotes are for identifiers and single quotes for string literals. By following thatyour code gets more portable. Same goes for `==` as comparison operator. Better use `=`.

For performance you want an index on `(id, ncode)`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've done very little SQL and am coming from R. Will switch it up.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is likely using a NOT EXISTS condition - should be something like:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    TABLE t
WHERE   t.code = "ABC"
        AND t.ncode = 1
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    TABLE ti
        WHERE   ti.id = t.id
                AND ti.ncode > 1
        );
```